# A model of a simple formula 'Exists([y],ForAll([x],Phi))' should be 'y=2' but Z3 it is returning '[]'

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, quantifiers

Note the following Z3-Py code:

```
x, y = Ints('x y')

negS0= (x >= 2)
s1 = (y > 1)
s2 = (y <= x)

s = Solver()
phi = Exists([y],ForAll([x], Implies(negS0, And(s1,s2))))
s.add(phi)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[]
```

My question is: why is the model empty? I mean, I think `y=2` should be a model...

Note that the same result happens with `x` and `y` being `Real`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z3 will not include any quantified variable (in your case neither `y` nor `x`) in its model. Note that you cannot put `x` in a model anyhow, because the formula is true for all `x`: That's the meaning of universal quantification. For the outer-most existentials (like your `y`), z3 can indeed print the model value for that, but it chooses not to do so since it can be confusing: Imagine you had a `phi2`, which also had an outer-most existential named `y`: How would you know which `y` it would be that it prints in the model?

So, z3 keeps things simple and simply prints the top-level declared variables in the model. And since a top-level declaration is equivalent to an outermost existential, you can simply drop it:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = Ints('x y')

negS0= (x >= 2)
s1 = (y > 1)
s2 = (y <= x)

s = Solver()
phi = ForAll([x], Implies(negS0, And(s1,s2)))
s.add(phi)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```py
sat
[y = 2]
```

like you predicted. Note that this `y` is unambiguous, since it's declared at the top-level. (Of course, you can redefine it to be something else due to the loosely typed nature of Python bindings and still get yourself confused, but that's a different discussion.)

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thanks as always! Just in case someone does not understand the answer, allow me to copy your reply in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082515/in-z3-i-cannot-understand-result-of-quantifier-elimination-of-exists-y-forall/), which I think that really clarifies this. "An outer-most existentially quantified variable in a formula, and a top-level declaration are equivalent. `(Exists([x], ...)`, vs. `x = Int('x'))`. The only difference is that you'll get a value in the models with the latter, and not for the former. So, always prefer the latter."

Comment: To be precise: All your `s.add(phi)` formulas are conjuncted, and then closed over with an `exists` declaration for every top-level variable. This is the meaning of a "formula" as you build the solver. Note that, confusingly, for each quantified variable, you also have to declare it at the top-level as well, but this is a mere technicality. I wish they didn't do that, but I also see that it's a simple solution to the classic "binder" problem: In a more typed embedding, one can use a HOAS (higher-order-abstract-syntax) to capture such variables. But Python isn't that nice.